# Implementing a notch filter of 50 Hz in MatLab

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm trying to implement a notch filter of 50 Hz in MatLab. Here is the code:

```
     subplot(2,1,2);
     %Fse = 220;
     time = 0:1/f:sB-1/f;
     x = buf;
     wo = 60 / (1000/2);
     bw = wo / 50;
     [b,a] = iirnotch(wo,bw);
     y = filter(b,a,x);
     ydft = fft(y);
     xdft = fft(x);
     plot(x,y);
```

The value of buf is `buf = zeros([fse*sB,numel(name)]);` and the sampling frequency is `220 Hz`
And I'm not getting expected results. Can you tell me that where am I wrong?
The current output is like:
[image: img]

Required output is something like this:
[image: img1]

I'm talking about 2nd graph. First graph is good.

Comment: It is much easier to help if you include what you expected and what you got.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. You have `x` (original) and `y` (filtered) - what sizes are they?  Your definition for `buf` is a matrix of zeros, so that can't be right, presumably you then fill it in with data?  You're taking the fft of them, then ignoring that (apparently) and plotting `x` and `y` against each other.

Comment: @nkjt: Initially size of `x` and `y` are `2200 4`. And when packets start flowing in, they get filled with data. When I plotted `ydft` and `xdft`, the result was almost similar, the line started from `0` in `y` axis. But that wasn't the result which I had expected. I hope this is clear now, could you please help me?

Comment: Well, it isn't "the line", it will be four lines, for a start.  What is the significance of 2200 x 4 - four different signals/channels? Can you describe in words what the second plot is supposed to be - i.e. if you were to label the axes, what would be the labels?

Comment: @nkjt: `2200*4` means that there are `4` channels. Second plot is supposed to be a plot of `FFT` signals. And the data flows in from `4` channels.

Comment: Plot of FFT signals **how**.  Amplitude, phase? One-sided, two-sided?  You don't want to plot them all against frequency? (Currently you're just plotting the raw output of `fft` against each other).

Comment: I'd go for `amplitude`. And two-sided is better. Yeah, I want to plot them against `frequency`.